# How do you display a progress bar within a gui

Tags: autohotkey

I have the progress bar displaying in a separate window, but cant get it to display in the same window as the Gui with text.

```
Gui,Add,Progress, b w200, in progress, downloading, downloading Exe
Gui,Add,Text,vStatus, See status bar for dowload progress
Gui,Show,w250 h375
Gosub blah ;where i update the progressbar

blah:
Progress,50
return
```

Comment: Take a look here: http://ahkscript.org/boards/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=4662 Maybe it can help you.

Comment: @vasili111, That link is great, but it looks like what I was doing... Can you explain why one of those examples shows up in the gui but mine shows up in a separate window?

Comment: I am not good at AutoHotkey GUIs. Maybe someone else can help you here. If you don't get answer here, then post your  question at http://ahkscript.org/boards/ .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty simple:

```
Gui, Add, Progress, w200 h20 -Smooth vMyProgress, 0
Gui,Add,Text,vStatus, See status bar for dowload progress
Gui,Show,w250 h375
GoSub, blah
Return

blah:
    GuiControl,, MyProgress, 50 
Return
```

Comment: is this `Gui, Add, Progress` the same as just the `Progress` command? cuz manual says a script can only have ten `Progress`, how can I display 20 progress bar at the same time? thx advanced.

Comment: No, `Progress` creates a dedicates windows with a progress bar. There is no limit as far as I'm aware when you use `Gui, Add, Progress`. To have more than one, just enter the line multiple times and obviously make sure to use unique variables.